# Non compact topologogical space with the cocontable topology of an uncountable set

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I seek to find an example of an uncountable set, with the cocountable topology, which is not compact.

**My Example:** Let our set be $X=\mathbb{R}$.  Then
$$
\mathcal{U}=\{ \mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{N} \cup {i} \mid i \in \mathbb{N} \}
$$
is an open cover, as note
$$
\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{U}}U.
$$
This has no finite subcovering.

**Question:** Is this example correct?

Comment: yes, this is correct. what is giving you pause?

Comment: Just thought it would be harder to seek such an example. If you can post this as an answer I will gladly accept it.

Comment: I mean to say that if you find this argument unsatisfying, it is probably important for you to work out any details that are bothering you. This isn't really about whether or not the argument is right, it's about whether you find it convincing. Mathematicians should be able to check their own work. 

For instance, if you pick a finite subset of the $\mathcal{U}$, can you demonstrate an element not in their union? Can you expand the definition of the union to show that $\bigcup_{U\in\mathcal{U}}U=\mathbb{R}$?